# Pass value from an html form in sidebar to google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have difficulties in this... I read the documentation but I'm not able to do it.

I want to create a little html form in a sidebar of a Google Document.
This form will pull the Contacts Group from Contacts so the user can chose one and pass t to my script.

This is what I've done:

Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

menu.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();

}

function showSidebar() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('Chose the Contact Group')
      .setWidth(300);

  var groups = ContactsApp.getContactGroups();

  // add this to the html file Page.html
  html.append ('<form onsubmit="google.script.run.myFunction(formObject)">'+
               '<select>');

  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    html.append('<option name="chosenGroup" value="' + groups[i].getName() + '">' + groups[i].getName() + '</option>');
  }

  html.append('</select><input type="submit">');

  //this is commented because I was testing it
  //html.append("<script>function handleFormSubmit(formObject) { google.script.run.myFunction(formObject); } </script>");

    DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);

}
```

Code.gs

```
myFunction (formObject) {

Logger.log(formObject.chosenGroup);

}
```

When I click on the submit button a new blank page is opened with a url like:

https://n-wuewuewuee98efgdsf98769s8d76f9s76df-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because of the 'action' attribute of the 'form' tag. When you submit a form, the browser is redirected to the route specified in the 'action' attribute. Usually, this URL pattern is mapped to the code on the server that receives data posted by the form.

There are other issues in your code that should be addressed first:

1) The doGet() function is needed only when you deploy the script as a web app. The code in doGet() executes when you open that app's URL in a browser, i.e. send a 'GET' request to the app. Your script is document-bound, so no need for doGet()

2) Separate aspects of your business logic. showSideBar() must do exactly what it's supposed to do, namely, show the sidebar. getContactGroups() must return the array of contact groups, etc.

3) Remember, you can pass variables to HTML pages and create UI dynamically using templated HTML. No need for appending line by line!
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

4) Finally, the redirect to another page can be easily solved by using jQuery.

See sample code below. My script was spreadsheet-bound, so all you have to do is replace SpreadsheetApp with DocumentApp.

Server code (main.gs)

```
function onOpen(){

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

ui.createMenu('Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();


}


function showSidebar() {

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar');

template.contactGroups = getContactGroups(); //adding contactGroups as a property of the template object. 

ui.showSidebar(template.evaluate()); //Calling evaluate() executes the inline JS code in sidebar.html, populating the dropdown list


}

function getContactGroups(){

try {

var contactGroups = ContactsApp.getContactGroups();

} catch(error) {

Logger.log(error);

}

return contactGroups;

}

function processFormResponse(formObject){


Logger.log(formObject.chosenGroup);



}
```

And here's sidebar.html. Note the special syntax for inline code within html files.  Calling e.preventDefault() takes care of the redirect to another page. Since we are adding contactGroups as a property to the template object, this variable will be available when evaluate() is called. The inline code below will dynamically populate the dropdown list with group names.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
        Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

        <form>
        <select name="chosenGroup">

        <? for (var i=0; i < contactGroups.length; i++) { ?>

        <option value="<?= contactGroups[i].getName()?>"><?= contactGroups[i].getName()?></option>


        <?}?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>



       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
       <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

              $('form').submit(function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                google.script.run.processFormResponse(this);


              });


        });

       </script>


      </body>
    </html>
```

**UPDATE**

There's nothing special about jQuery. It's a JS library designed to make navigating the DOM tree a bit easier, but it's built on top of the same DOM API in your browser.  Long story short, you don't need jQuery to achieve this result. 
1) Assign a unique id to your 'form' tag, e.g.

```
<form id="form">
```

2) Create a function that adds an event listener to the form that listens to the 'submit' event. The 2nd argument is the event handler function. Using 'click' instead of 'submit' will force you to create the form object manually by referencing text fields by id and getting user input.

```
   <script>
      function addEventListeners() {

       document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){

       e.preventDefault();
       google.script.run.processFormResponse(this);


       });



       }
      </script>
```

Finally, call this function on load.

```
<body onLoad="addEventListeners()">
```

The jQuery code in my previous example did exactly the same thing, but was much more readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: Thank you Anton, is it working but I cant' understand why we need jquery here, is not possible to add "google.script.run.processFormResponse(this);" in an onlick? but maybe I misunderstood this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms (is for web apps and not form bound scripts, right?)