# How to create resuable showModalDialog() in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have ModalDialog that prompts for user date range selection in order to generate the appropriate info. I have several menu items that uses the same prompt so I want to reuse the ModalDialog.

```
// Available method
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Options for Menu Item N');

// What I hope is available
SpreadsheetApp.getUI().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Options for Menu Item N', userdataN); // pseudocode
// inside HTML
var userdata = Script.host.environment // pseudocode do something with userdata in HTML
```

However, the showModalDialog() function does not allow me to pass any user data to the html so I have no way to identify which menu item I need to return the user selection to.

How can I create a reusable ModelDialog in this case?

EDIT:
I realized I can write the environment variable value in a sheet and then later from the HTML retrieve the value, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your whole script and actual situation, for example, how about using [the templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) and/or [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) for `htmlOutput`? By using them, you can give the values to the HTML. If I misunderstood your question and this was not suitable for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: I am embarrased to ask someone with your reputation to re-read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question to provide more and relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either pass the user data object as a property of the HtmlTemplate object and use scriptlet syntax (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502796/pass-value-from-an-html-form-in-sidebar-to-google-script/44504594#44504594)) or do string interpolation. Personally, I prefer the latter option over using Google's built-in template engine. It's slower but much more flexible.

Suppose we have an HTML page called 'app' in the script editor

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{global.app}}</h1>
    <div id=container>
      <ul>
        <li>{{name}}</li>
        <li>{{email}}</li>
        <li>{{age}}</li>
      </ul>
      Created by {{global.author}}.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can call HtmlService methods to serve the template as a string.

```
 //serve HTML template as a string
function getTemplateAsString(filename) {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).getRawContent();    
}
```

You can then pass the html string to the interpolation function:

```
var config = {
     app: "My app",
     author: "me"
   };

function interpolateString(htmlString, params) {

    //Add global variables to the template
  for (var configKey in config) {
    if (config.hasOwnProperty(configKey)) {
      htmlString = htmlString.replace("{{global." + configKey + "}}", config[configKey]);
    }
  }

  //Insert page-specific parameters
  for (var paramsKey in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(paramsKey)) {
      htmlString  = htmlString.replace("{{" + paramsKey + "}}", params[paramsKey]);
    } 
  }

  return htmlString;

}
```

For the last step, you create the HtmlTemplate object from the resulting string and call the 'evaluate()' method on it. Calling evaluate returns a valid HtmlOutput object instance that you can pass to  UI methods

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(htmlString);
ui.showModalDialog(template.evaluate(), "My dialog");
```

Comment: This is a dirty good idea! I'll wait for a few days to see if any more better ways before I mark this as answer. Thank you!